# How can I update excel inventory by typing something in user input?

Tags: python, excel, excel-2010

I am a newbie to python thus am struggling a bit. I’m not sure the extent of what I need to share for someone to help me, so I just shared all context just in case. However, if the context isn’t needed please feel free to disregard the earlier passages and simply skip to the bolded region.

*The premise of my project:*

At my work I keep track of the inventory of merchandise. In the excel, we use, there 5 separate grids on one sheet for every type of merch we have. For example, hoodies are columns A to F (for a smaller version of what the excel looks like please refer to the screenshot at the very bottom).

Every time, while I sell merch I have to go into excel and manually update the inventory by changing the numbers sold column. It takes a while thus I want to code something in python that makes this easier.

*Idea for how the code works:*

My idea for this project is when a customer comes to me to buy merchandise, instead of manually scrolling through excel, finding the right type of merch, the right colour row and size column, then updating the sold count, I would have a function that asks for user input. If the customer wants, let's say a hoodie that is red, that is in size L, I just type hrl into the user input and my code automatically finds the cell that corresponds to this.

My idea was that by typing ex: hryl, my code would recognize the h in my input and narrow down the area in excel to a specific column range that highlights all hoodies. The r narrows down the area in excel to a specific range of rows for the colour red.

When these two things cross it highlights a specific area on excel. Then my code would take the yl input from hryl and find the cell within this crossover area that has the letter yl typed into it.

This cell would be the cell with yl written in it, next to the red rows under the columns for hoodies in my screenshot. The code would then take that cell, move to the right by 2, and add 1 to it (since that is where the sold column for that specific merch item is located)

*Additional context:*

Since I am a newbie I wanted to first create an easier version of what I just laid out. I decided to create an excel spreadsheet with merch (a small scale version) to kind of just test my idea out (the screenshot is below). I only inputted 1 colour for hoodies with only 3 sizes for simplicity.

**The issue:**

This is the code I have so far. I wanted to first write code to test if writing hryl (representing hoodie, red, size Youth Large) into my function input will update the sold column for that piece of merchandise.  For my code, the range for columns is represented by (1,6) for hoodies, and since the r in hrl represents red, the row for that is represented by range(3,6). The line underneath that to my understanding combines the rows and columns and represents only the crossover cells. Thus this brings me to my current issue. I am trying to write the next line of code, which is supposed to search the crossover cells for a cell number (cell number as in A1, B2 etc. I’m not sure what the term for that is) that has the letter L written in it. My code would then move 2 times to the right of that cell, and update this new cell (the newly arrived cell) by +1.

I am trying to use a for loop that loops over the crossover cells to find the cell number that has L written in it. However, sometimes when I do that it keeps on saying the cell is not iterable and idk what to do. I looked up online on what to do and I’ve seen something about dp.at, but I’m still confused.

Can someone help me with this to make it work?

Thanks!

my screenshot:
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqs3i.png)

my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/Angela Shen/Downloads/Python gc merch project.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
 
        

def inventory_update(merchpurchased):
    #for t shirts and hoodies
    if "h" in merchpurchased:
        for col in range (1,6):
            for row in range(3,6):
                char = get_column_letter(col)                
                crossover_cells = (ws[char + str(row)])
                for x in crossover_cells:
                    if x == 'L':
                        #x+2 == +1??
                            

    else: 
        print("not a valid input")
              

inventory_update('hrl')
```

Comment: You explain how you edit this in Googlesheets. BUT then you provide an example using Excel. You need to decide one or the other.

Comment: oops, maybe my explanation is confusing :,(. I edited the question again, I am sticking with using excel